# Error: "Property 'setIn' does not exist on type 'Map<any, any>'"

Tags: angular, redux, immutable.js

I'm (fairly) new to Immutable.js and Redux (and Angular2) and getting the error in the title (I get an error both for setIn and getIn). The error comes from my store.ts. Here's the short version:

```js
import { Action as reduxAction, Reducer, combineReducers } from 'redux';
import { ActionActions } from './actions/action.actions';
import { UserActions } from './actions/user.actions';
import { MetaActions } from './actions/meta.actions';
import { Action } from './app/library/action/class.action';
import * as Immutable from 'immutable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

export interface IAppState {
    action: IActionState
}

export interface IActionState {
    action?: Map<any, any>
}

export const INITIAL_STATE: IAppState = {
    action: {
        action: null
    }
}

export function actionReducer(lastState: IActionState, action) 
{
    // Initial action state
    if (undefined === lastState) {
        lastState = {
            action: null
        }
    }

    // Switching
    switch(action.type)
    {
        case ActionActions.REMOVE_EMPLOYEE:
        {
            return { action: lastState.action.setIn(['employees', action.value.role], 
                lastState.action.getIn(['employees', action.value.role])
                .filter(o => o.getIn(['employee','employeeId']) !== action.value.employeeId)) };
        }  
    }
    
    return { action: lastState.action }
}
```

(Please don't be confused that the object I'm working on also happens to be named "action". It's a bit unlucky in the context of Redux but it does make sense in the context of the application as such.)

When the compiler (transpiler?) runs in the terminal I get the error in the title but the script works just fine when I run the website. No problem at all. Just the error in the terminal.

If I try running Immutable.map.isMap() on the action-object it returns true. Also methods get() and set() seems to exist on the object.

So if it in fact is a Map and set() and get() works - why not setIn() and getIn()? To be clear - they do work - perfectly. I just get an error in the terminal.

I can use setIn() and getIn() elsewhere in the application. Even on the same object. So why not in the store.ts? Is it a problem in my imports?

Answer (score 2):

Okay - after many intensive meetings between forehead and wall it seems I have solved the issue myself.

I imported the Immutable.js library as such:

```
import * as Immutable from 'immutable';
```

And then I instantiated the (interface for the) object like so:

```
action?: Map<any, any>
```

When it should have been

```
action?: Immutable.Map<any, any>
```

Apparently this works.

This maybe seems obvious for some, but I was thrown off because Immutable.map.isMap() evaluated true.